# Redux-Form FieldArray subform errors

Tags: redux-form, react-redux-form

I would like to extend an official redux-form example with FieldArray:
http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/examples/fieldArrays/

What I need is to possibility to add e.g red border around each member subform if inputs are invalid and form has been submitted. 
How can I achieve this ? I know I can pass

```
errors.members._error = "error msg"
```

but it's a global error for whole members subforms and I would like to check if any member subform is invalid and if it is then add red border to this subform.